# Are downvotes being counted the same as upvotes in the Reputation summary?

Tags: bug, down-votes, reputation

## My home page for politics.SE shows "+4" votes for this question:

[image]

---

## But in fact, there was 1 upvote and 3 downvotes:

[image]

---

I successfully(!?) have negative values for other questions though.

So is something broken?

UPDATE:

Others seem to be wrong too:
[image]

The "+10" actually has (+6 -1 ✓).

The "-2" at the bottom actually has (+85 -9).

Am I completely missing what this "Reputation" section means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The +4 relates to the total amount of rep points obtained, not the number of votes; upvotes add 10 points while downvotes subtract 2. 10-3*2 = 4

Note that the Reputation box in the profile summary only shows recent reputation events - see this [related meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320202/what-determines-whether-the-reputation-amount-on-my-profiles-reputation-tab-is) - not overall totals of reputation gained from a post. You can see the full breakdowns [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/27691/ray-butterworth?tab=reputation).

Comment: I think that's just a coincidence.  I've added a couple of other examples.

Comment: @RayButterworth ah, I see where your confusion comes from - I agree that it's not incredibly intuitive. See my update.

Comment: Thanks.  It would be a lot less confusing though if it were labeled something like "Recent Reputation Changes".  And even better if it also said what "Recent" meant.